# What is the full Android alarm sound URI?

Tags: android, uri, android-mediaplayer, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Do you guys know what is the full URI for alarm sound in different version of android?

I got this

**03-15 02:54:42.043: I/alert(2073): content://settings/system/alarm_alert**

When I used this

```
Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
```

But it just worked when I tried to play media player on android 18. I used it on android 8, 18 and 19 and I just got positive result on android 18. This happen not only on emulator, but also, on real devices.

When I try to play sound from raw folder I don't have nay problem in any version of android.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: are you sure the alarms volume of ur phone is not zero?

Comment: Yes, I can here other voices .